# How to created Action/render/portlet URL using javascript in Liferay?

Tags: javascript, url, liferay

I am unable to create action/portlet url using javascript in Liferay.

```
<aui:script use="liferay-util-window,liferay-portlet-url">
  var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.create(--Nothing shows on IDE autocomplete post this)
</aui:script>
```

Edit:
I am using Eclipse IDE but on typing in "Liferay.PortletURL.create" it does not provide any automcomplete option to create either of action/render or for that matter URL at all.
I am using Liferay-6.2-ce-GA2 plugins sdk.

Are there no autocomplete available for using javascript create URL or has this been replaced by some new JS functions in liferay?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "does not support/provide"? What do you do?  What you expect to happen and what happens instead? What errors you see in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the resource URL as given below:

```
 AUI().use('aui-base', 'aui-io-request', 'liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {
    var A = AUI();
    var myResourceURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();

    myResourceURL.setResourceId('resourceID');

    myResourceURL.setParameter("action","youractionthatwilltriggercontroller");                                         
A.io.request(myResourceURL.toString(), {
                            method : 'post',
                            dataType : 'text',

                            on : {
                            start : function() {

                                //Your operations
                              },
                            success : function() {
                                    // your operations
                                },
                                    failure : function() {
                                    },
                                    complete : function() {
                                    },
                                    end : function() {
                                    },
```

To create the render URL you can use the code as given below :

```
var url = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();

url.setPortletId(pid);

url.setParameter("action", "Your-action-to-trigger");

url.setPortletMode("view");

url.setWindowState("normal");

window.location = url.toString();
```

To create the action URL , just use :

```
var url = Liferay.PortletURL.createActionURL(); 

url.setPortletId(pid);

url.setParameter("action", "your-action");

url.setPortletMode("view");

url.setWindowState("normal");

window.href = url.toString();
```

I hope this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Will check and confirm!

Answer (score 0):

> Are there no autocomplete available for using javascript create URL

There is no autocomplete because you could create ANY url this way. There is no way for the IDE to know what is reasonable suggestion in your particular case.